# Timing? - cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, timer

How would I be able to use timers? For example I want to show a certain text for 10 seconds and then I want to show a different text for the rest of the duration.

Thanks,

Kevin

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to defer an action is to use NSObject's performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:

```
- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
```

Set your text the first time (or at init time) and then do something like:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(changeText) withObject:nil afterDelay:10.0];
```

You can cancel the request with:

```
+ (void)cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:(id)aTarget selector:(SEL)aSelector object:(id)anArgument
```

which you will need to do if you want your object to be deallocated as performSelector retains both your object and the withObject parameter.

Comment: The docs say that performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: retains the receiver and the withObject.  So your object will not be deallocated until that selector is performed.

Comment: But you don't have to cancel if the selector does get performed right?

Comment: Correct.  Essentially, the system retains both the receiver (self in this case) and the withObject, waits around 10 seconds, then invokes the method and releases the receiver and withObject.  A consequence is that neither the receiver nor the withObject can be deallocated in the mean time.

Answer (score 2):

Start with the [Timer Programming Topics for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html).

Answer (score 1):

[NSTimer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).